# Jackson asText() - printing empty string

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

```
public class abc {
    @JsonRawValue
    @JsonDeserialize(using =abc.JsonAsStringDeserializer.class)
    private String  a1;
    private String a2;
}
```

```
   public static final class JsonAsStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
                throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode tree = objectMapper.readTree(jsonParser);
            return tree.toString(); //want to use asText() here as toString doesn't always give valid json.
        }
    }
```

I have an issue while deserializing using the custom deserializer and using asText() Jackson's method.

`Serialized output comes out to be like this "{\"a1\":{\"dummy\":\"value\"},\"a2\":\"some data\"}";`

In the custom deserializer (JsonAsStringDeserializer), the value comes out to be `{"dummy":"value"}` as a1 is only using custom deserializer.

I would like to return the entire string `{"dummy":"value"}` in the custom deserializer. This works fine when I use toString() method, however when I use tree.asText()[want to use this to get valid json], it returns empty string. I looked the documentation of asText(), where it says that to use asText(), JsonNode needs to be a ValueNode. Is there something I can do regarding this? I would like to use asText() to get the valid json. I also looked at textValue() and it has the same issue as asText().

Is there any way to make this `{"dummy":"value"}` ValueNode in Jackson and return using tree.asText(). I tried casting it and it doesn't work.

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make some changes to your deserializer:

```java
public class JsonAsStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
           throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jp);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to find but does this return ```return mapper.writeValueAsString(node);``` valid json?